# How to validate the height of the element in % value in selenium using Java

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got the height of the element in px values by using:
`element.getCssValue("height")`

But by using this, i got the height as:
**Height: 560px**

But I need to get the height as:
**Height: 100%**
Or like **Height: 50%**

Comment: What do you want it to be a percentage of? Window height or monitor height?

Comment: Window height means view screens height?  I don't know about this question, let me try to explain this. I need the components height when it's opened in full screen mode like calendar and for some text area fields.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want to replace px with %?
if yes then use string replace method

Comment: No, i want to get the height value in percentage

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get the percentage of the element in relation to the height of the window:

```
double heightPercentage = element.getCssValue("height") / driver.Manage().Window.Size.Height;
```

Comment: Can u pls explain why we have to divide it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way to just get the percentage of the element. Dividing is how you calculate the percentage of one amount towards another

Answer (score 0):

This'll help i guess:

1.
int hei = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
int pxtopercen = (int) (hei*6.25);

2.
driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();